# Variable loose it's value

Tags: c++

I've met the following issue. I have some classes:

```
class classA
{
public:
    std::vector< classB > elementsOfBClass;
}

classA::classA()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b[2] = {2,3};
    elementsOfBClass.pushBack(classB(a,b));
}

class classB
{
public:
    int a;
    int* b;

    classB(int a, int* b);
};

classB::classB(int aVal, int* bVal)
{
    a = aVal;
    b = bVal;
    LOG("%d",a);  // a=1 
    LOG("%d,%d",b[0],b[1]); //b[0] = 2 , b[1] = 3
    //If I output b[0] and b[1] here then it's ok
}
```

And also I have some code that uses this class:

```
classA classAObject = classA();
LOG("%d", classAObject.elementsOfClassB[0].a);  // a=1
LOG("%d,%d",classAObject.elementsOfClassB[0].b[0],classAObject.elementsOfClassB[0].b[1]); //Here is some strange issue. b[0] and b[1] is always some absolutely random values!
```

b[0] and b[1] is some strange values. Can you please help me to understand why?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How are you expecting to manage the lifetime of whatever `b` points to? And why are you using pointers at all? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You store a pointer to local variable `int b[2]` in your vector. `b` is destroyed when `classA` constructor exits, leaving a dangling pointer in the vector.  To fix this, you could change `classB` to have `std::array<int,2> b;` , or `std::vector<int> b;` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classB::b member does not make a copy of b, simply takes a pointer to a variable allocated on the stack. That gets overwritten when ClassA contructr exits.

Your classB should hold a member declared as b[2] ad make a deep copy of `int *bVal`

Answer (score 0):

If you have choice, use smart pointers and std::containers such as std::array (if size is known at compile-time, C++11 required) or std::vector. It will save you from headaches.